# What constitutes "seeing a Faceless unmasked"?

Tags: apocalypse-world

The Faceless playbook of Apocalypse World (both 1e and 2e limited playbooks) states the following:

> **The Unexpected:** when someone sees you unmasked for the first time, they take s-harm, in addition to anything else that happens.

Does that apply only to the moment of unmasking, or seeing the Faceless without the mask in general? I think the former makes more sense in the narrative, but feel the latter is a more natural interpretation of the wording.

Comment: I see the conflict -- "unmasked" could be read either as a verb or an adjective here ("see you have your masked remove" vs "see you without your mask").

Answer (score 5):

I am in favour of reading it as "whenever somebody sees you without your mask on and recognizes you".

Mechanically, because the next feature reads

> **Unmasked, you are (choose 2):** Vulnerable...Grotesque...Afraid...Irresolute..Ashamed...Powerless

Which implies two possible states: mask on / mask off. And equates "Unmasked" with the "while the mask is off".

Narratively, that makes as much sense. Whenever someone realizes what the Faceless really looks like, that changes their perspective. Witnessing the act of taking the mask off is not required unless the Faceless can convincingly pass for somebody else without it.

Comment: I disagree with it making more sense narratively - the Faceless is a masked rogue, who tend to leave double lifes in fiction. Private life with the mask off, public life with the mask on. I thought the s-harm was supposed to emulate the shock of seeing that the masked vigilante was actually a billionaire playboy, as seen in Batman franchise from time to time.

Comment: Well, no, the Faceless is a scary-as-f@#$ chainsaw-massacring maniac who you also live with in a tight post-apocalyptic community. When you see how he looks as a 'mortal' person, rather than the primal spawn of horror, you are going to be shocked. I have doubts that it changes when you simply walk on him, still recognizable with his chainsaw and bloody armour, without the mask on and not witness him taking the mask off.

Comment: And sorry SE,  that 'scary-as' part is an almost direct quote from the playbook.

Comment: I guess there's many flavors on how the Faceless and their mask are related, and the sanest way to interpret this would depend on how a particular mask wears their Faceless.

Comment: @kviiri No, the Faceless is not a masked vigilante playbook in any interpretation. Their mask is their real face, as far as they are concerned, and don't take it off. They don't have a double life, they have just one.

Comment: For me, it is obviously implied that having the mask on is a normal state of the Faceless playbook, since he starts suffering some mostly psychological drawbacks when he takes it off.

Comment: Here's some background on the playbook: [“I noticed a lack of a playbook for huge monsters wearing masks like the Humungus or Blaster…”](http://apocalypse-world.com/forums/index.php?topic=80.0)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Got any statement to back that up? I kinda took the Norman Osborn reference as a cue to play the Faceless as one, and don't see anything explicitly against it in the playbooks.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, thanks, didn't know about the background behind the playbook. Do you think I can do something to improve the answer according to these comments?

Comment: @Nox I'm not sure. Unless kviiri wants to put the idea that the Faceless is a double-life roguish superhero into the question, it's hard to address (and maybe unnecessary).

Comment: @Nox If you can think of a movie scene that fits, might be worthwhile to reference it and say "the goal of this mechanic is something that feels like this."